# Go and Redisgo: DialURL error: NOAUTH Authentication required

Tags: go, redis

I'm trying to connect to my Redis server using Go and [redigo](https://github.com/garyburd/redigo) with a URI that works on another application, written in Java with [lettuce](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce). On the Go project, I'm getting the error

> NOAUTH Authentication required.

My `redis.conf` has `requirepass true`, and I pass the password in the URI. Here's how I connect:

```
conn, err := redis.DialURL("redis://MySecurePassword@localhost:6666/0")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Not able to connect to Redis")
    }
```

No errors there. The error shows when I try to run a command to retrieve data.

```
writeOrErr(&b, conn, "HGETALL", "mykey")

// Wrapper for redis.Conn.Do that writes the result to a buffer or reports the error
func writeOrErr(b *bytes.Buffer, conn redis.Conn, cmd string, key string) string {
    result, err := conn.Do(cmd, key)
    if err != nil {
        // !!! THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE !!!
        log.Fatalf("Couldn't run %s \"%s\" | Error: %s", cmd, key, err.Error())
    }

    // Retrieve data
    _, err = b.WriteString(result.(string))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Couldn't write result to string for " + key)
    }

    return result.(string)
}
```

Am I using *redigo*'s API improperly? How can I make it connect?

Comment: Can you also show the command to run the data?

Comment: @CeriseLimón I updated `DialURL` with the explicit value.

Comment: The URL does not match [the redis URI scheme specification](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/redis). The userinfo field should be in the format  "user:password".

Comment: @BenjaminKadish I added the code that retrieves the data, I commented on top of the line where the error occurs.

Comment: @CeriseLimón you are right. I saw the URI scheme before posting here. But the URI I used worked with Java's lettuce so I figured it would work everywhere. I was wrong. Please post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL does not match the [redis URI scheme specification](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/redis). The userinfo field should be in the format "user:password"